# How do anomalies work in the causal formulation of QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, symmetry, renormalization, quantum-anomalies

In the [Epstein-Glaser formulation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/causal+perturbation+theory) of a QFT, the would-be divergences are taken care of by meticulously splitting the distributions that appear in the construction of the $S$-matrix (or correlation functions). As a result, there are no divergences anywhere and the theory is perfectly rigorous<sup>1</sup>.

How do anomalies fit into this picture? These can be understood as the clash between a symmetry of the action and a regulator that refuses to respect it. In more pragmatical terms, the symmetry would be restored if the regulator is removed, so it is $\mathcal O(\epsilon^n)$, while the divergences are $\mathcal O(\epsilon^{-m})$; and, if $n=m$, a finite piece survives the physical limit $\epsilon\to 0$. But in the EG formulation, there are no divergences and no regulators, so how do anomalies arise? What is their precise role?

---

<sup>1: and – naturally – it agrees, in a general sense, with what naïve perturbation theory predicts; formally speaking, in the EG formulation the would-be divergences are recast as polynomials in the external momenta, i.e., they are subtracted in momentum space, in the sense of [BPHZ](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bogoliubov-Parasiuk-Hepp-Zimmermann_renormalization_scheme).</sup>

Comment: Did I say something wrong? The downvote is actually irrelevant, but if there is anything wrong here I'd like to know. A comment is much more useful (for me and for anyone reading the post in the future). Thanks!

Comment: wasn't me, but my guess is some might not have liked "the EG formulation is essentially the same idea behind BPHZ".

Comment: Yeah I get it. The wording is really bad. What I meant is that the "regularisation" in EG is essentially what BPHZ call "subtraction in momentum space". That is, in both cases the divergences are recast as polynomials (of degree $\omega$, the superficial degree of divergence) in the external momenta. I agree that "the EG formulation is essentially the same idea behind BPHZ" is just wrong. (For the record, Bogoliubov did also work in the formulation of the causal approach, that's why EG and BPHZ share some characteristics. But they are definitely not "essentially the same idea"). I'll fix it.

Comment: I actually think "the EG formulation is essentially the same idea behind BPHZ" is not that wrong. EG works in position space while usual treatments of BPHZ are in momentum space. However, the distinction position vs. momentum space is rather moot. BPHZ can very well be done in position space as in the book by Rivasseau or the recent article by Martin Hairer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anomalies may (or may not) appear as obstructions in the proof of the Ward-Takahashi identities, which provide gauge invariance. See

D.R. Grigore, The structure of the anomalies of gauge theories in the causal approach, J. Physics A: Math. Gen. 35 (2002), 1665.

See also [Chapter 15 (Interacting quantum fields)](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/newideaofquantumfieldtheory-interactingquantumfields/) from the recent course ''Mathematical quantum field theory'' by Urs Schreiber.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I'll take some time for me to digest the paper, but it looks quite good (BTW, if you also happen to know a *textbook* reference where this issue is addressed, that would be awesome). Thanks!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: maybe it is in Scharf's ghost book (referenced in my note https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/causal-perturbation-theory/ ) - but I don't have the book ready for checking.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: I added a reference to a course from the current winter term. It is close to the textbook treatment you asked for.